# beginner - issue when moving from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-debug

I'm very new to application development and I'm getting an error of Application has stopped unexpectedly when moving between secondActivity and threelayer. Code for the both follows below:

**SecondAcivity**

```
package com.example.expandinglists;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Remove TitleBar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //The line below sets the convas / area labelled as activity_main
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        // Remove notification bar.        
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //Declaring Button
        setupNavigationButton();
    }



    //button class
      private void setupNavigationButton() {
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOnSecond);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    //The code below displays text when the button is pressed
                    //Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,"You Clicked it on  2nd Activity",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, threelayer.class));

                    //finish();
                }           
            });         
        }
      //End of button class




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }
```

**threelayer**

```
package com.androidhub4you.multilevellistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.androidhub4you.multilevellistview.Product.SubCategory;
import com.androidhub4you.multilevellistview.Product.SubCategory.ItemList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class threelayer extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<Product>pProductArrayList;
    private ArrayList<SubCategory>pSubItemArrayList;
    private ArrayList<SubCategory>pSubItemArrayList2;
    private LinearLayout mLinearListView;
    boolean isFirstViewClick=false;
    boolean isSecondViewClick=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_threelayer);
        mLinearListView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_listview);

        /**
         * 
         */

        ArrayList<ItemList> mItemListArray=new ArrayList<ItemList>();
        mItemListArray.add(new ItemList("Red", "20"));
        mItemListArray.add(new ItemList("Blue", "50"));
        mItemListArray.add(new ItemList("Red", "20"));
        mItemListArray.add(new ItemList("Blue", "50"));

        ArrayList<ItemList> mItemListArray2=new ArrayList<ItemList>();
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Pant", "2000"));
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Shirt", "1000"));
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Pant", "2000"));
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Shirt", "1000"));
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Pant", "2000"));
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Shirt", "1000"));


        /**
         * 
         */
        pSubItemArrayList=new ArrayList<SubCategory>();
        pSubItemArrayList2=new ArrayList<SubCategory>();
        pSubItemArrayList.add(new SubCategory("Color", mItemListArray));
        pSubItemArrayList2.add(new SubCategory("Cloths", mItemListArray2));
        pSubItemArrayList.add(new SubCategory("Color", mItemListArray));
        pSubItemArrayList2.add(new SubCategory("Cloths", mItemListArray2));
        /**
         * 
         */

        pProductArrayList=new ArrayList<Product>();
        pProductArrayList.add(new Product("Emotions", pSubItemArrayList));
        pProductArrayList.add(new Product("Garments", pSubItemArrayList2));


        /***
         * adding item into listview
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < pProductArrayList.size(); i++) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = null;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View mLinearView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_first, null);

            final TextView mProductName = (TextView) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            final RelativeLayout mLinearFirstArrow=(RelativeLayout)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.linearFirst);
            final ImageView mImageArrowFirst=(ImageView)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.imageFirstArrow);
            final LinearLayout mLinearScrollSecond=(LinearLayout)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll);

            if(isFirstViewClick==false){
            mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
            }
            else{
                mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
            }

            mLinearFirstArrow.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    if(isFirstViewClick==false){
                        isFirstViewClick=true;
                        mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                        mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }else{
                        isFirstViewClick=false;
                        mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                        mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
                    }
                    return false;
                } 
            });


            final String name = pProductArrayList.get(i).getpName();
            mProductName.setText(name);

            /**
             * 
             */
            for (int j = 0; j < pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().size(); j++) {

                LayoutInflater inflater2 = null;
                inflater2 = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View mLinearView2 = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.row_second, null);

                TextView mSubItemName = (TextView) mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
                final RelativeLayout mLinearSecondArrow=(RelativeLayout)mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.linearSecond);
                final ImageView mImageArrowSecond=(ImageView)mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.imageSecondArrow);
                final LinearLayout mLinearScrollThird=(LinearLayout)mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll_third);

                if(isSecondViewClick==false){
                    mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                    }
                    else{
                        mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                    }

                mLinearSecondArrow.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                            if(isSecondViewClick==false){
                                isSecondViewClick=true;
                                mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                                mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }else{
                                isSecondViewClick=false;
                                mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                                mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
                            }
                            return false;
                        } 
                    });


                final String catName = pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getpSubCatName();
                mSubItemName.setText(catName);
                /**
                 * 
                 */
                  for (int k = 0; k < pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getmItemListArray().size(); k++) {

                        LayoutInflater inflater3 = null;
                        inflater3 = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        View mLinearView3 = inflater3.inflate(R.layout.row_third, null);

                        TextView mItemName = (TextView) mLinearView3.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemName);
                        TextView mItemPrice = (TextView) mLinearView3.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemPrice);
                        final String itemName = pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getmItemListArray().get(k).getItemName();
                        final String itemPrice = pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getmItemListArray().get(k).getItemPrice();
                        mItemName.setText(itemName);
                        mItemPrice.setText(itemPrice);

                        mLinearScrollThird.addView(mLinearView3);
                  }

                mLinearScrollSecond.addView(mLinearView2);

            }

            mLinearListView.addView(mLinearView);
        }       
    }

}
```

It's probably something minor.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

J

Comment: That's a lot of code. Post your stacktrace from the crash.

Comment: "Stopped unexpectedly" means you most likely got an unhandled exception in your code somewhere. Might I suggest using the platform tool's *logcat* to identify the cause of the problem? See https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Comment: Thanks for your comments and replies guys, it  was an issue with the android manifest file. Thanks for your replies though

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was an issue with the android manifest file. If you're a beginner and experimenting with preset code when faced with an error saying that the application has stopped unexpectedly, ensure that the manifest file is configured as intended.